# How to get status of Spark jobs on YARN using REST API?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

A spark application can run many jobs.  My spark is running on yarn.  Version 2.2.0.

How to get job running status and other info for a given application id, possibly using REST API?

job like follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pazaB.png)

Comment: Would you consider Spark REST API to get the info --> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api?

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but putting it for convenience. Hope it helps. You can use below Rest API command to get the status of any jobs running on YARN.

curl --negotiate -s -u : -X GET 'http://resourcemanagerhost:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_121766109986_12343/state'

O/P - {"state":"RUNNING"}

Throughout the job cycle the state will vary from  NEW, NEW_SAVING, SUBMITTED, ACCEPTED, RUNNING, FINISHED, FAILED, KILLED

You can use jq for a formatted output.

curl --negotiate -s -u : -X GET 'http://resourcemanagerhost:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_121766109986_12343'| jq .app.state

O/P - "RUNNING"

Answer (score 0):

YARN has a [Cluster Applications API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_API).  This shows the state along with other information.  To use it:

```
$ curl 'RMURL/ws/v1/cluster/apps/APP_ID'
```

with your application id as APP_ID.

It provides:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Based on **app-name**, just incase if you need

  `curl http://YARN_UI_IP:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps  | jq '.apps | select(.app != null) | .app | map(select(.name == "my-spark-job-name"))'`
  [image]